# Visio 2003: relationship arrow to connect 2 tables in Database ER diagrams

Tags: database, visio, entity-relationship

I am trying to model relationship between 2 tables Orders and OrderDetails. I draw "relationship" arrow from OrderDetails to Orders table with Foreign key OrderID. But in DatabaseProperties for relationship arrow, I get unknown parent and unknown child. How do I connect the 2 tables with relationship arrow properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Make sure you are picking the relationship arrow from the Entity Relationship stencil.
2. Drop the connector (arrow) on the surface.
3. Pick the top of the arrow and drag into middle of the `Orders` table
4. Pick the other end and drag into middle of the `OrderDetails` table.

You can also select fields to connect in "Arrow definition tab".
No need to specify foreign key in advance, it will auto-add once you make connection with the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

*I had the same problem too, but I managed to solve it by just dragging and dropping the relationship arrow to the tables where I want to have relationship. Just wait for the red outline before you'll gonna drop the relationship arrow to the table. And then, drag the end point to another table observing the same steps. You can also change the relationship type and cardinality under the "Miscellaneous" category.*

Answer (score -1):

I struggled a bit with this and finally figure out what I did wrong.

- Basically, after you picking the relationship arrow from the Entity Relationship stencil. You move your cursor  to the parent table.
- After a slight delay, the border box of the table will change into bolded red.
- Then you Drag it by holding the left mouse key to the child table you want to create relationship with.
- Now, here is where we make the mistake, you have to HOLD the mouse button, DO NOT let the button go until the child table box border turn into red. The mistake I made simply was because I was not patient enough. The delay was just a tad longer than my patient. If you wait a second or two longer the border will turn into RED. Then you are safe to let the left mouse button go.

Again, the key is to let the mouse button go only after the child table border turn into red!

Comment: Thanks Rohit, That looked a whole lot better. First time post. got go easy on me. LOL

Comment: Actually, **I think my post gave people the real answer to this question.** The previous proved answer actually did not. I read that but it did not help. I still struggled and tried to figure out what went wrong. Wasn't planned to post, just want to contribute a little to this community. But your vote down will have people searching for the answer miss my post, It is a bit unfortunate for them.